# Why getters and actions are arrow fucntions?

Tags: vuex

All in vue and mutation in vuex are regular functions.

But actions and getters in vuex are not.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see them either as method declarations or expressions (arrow functions). Usually I see getters as arrow functions to take advantage of the implicit return.

Example:

```
getItem: state => state.item
```

But this could potentially be written as:

```
getItem(state) {
  return state.item
}
```

In my experience, simple methods that only that need a return are a good candidate for an arrow function. So it could be thought of as a shorthand to achieve the same result.